# How to write a selenium c# x unit test for performing crud operations without making changes to the actual database?

Tags: c#, selenium, crud, xunit

My program has a page that displays a table as well as buttons to add/edit/delete users. I wrote selenium tests that simulate clicking those buttons and entering in user info and submitting the form.  The problem with this is I am making changes to my database as well as I have to keep changing the values of the keys I am sending in each time I run my tests.  I don't know how to simulate/test these cases without doing so.  This is my test for adding a user:

```
[Fact]
        public void AddUserSuccessfully()
        {
            var email = "anotheradd@gmail.com";

            using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseUrl.testUserUrl);

            var login = new Login(driver);
            login.EnterEmail();
            login.EnterPassword();
            login.HitSubmit();

            var users = new Users(driver);
            users.ClickOnAddUser();
            users.EnterFirstName("Anita");
            users.EnterLastName("Work");
            users.EnterEmail(email);
            users.EnterPassword("P*$sW0rd");
            users.ConfirmPassword("P*$sW0rd");
            users.EnterRole("Developer");
            Pause.SimulatePause();
            var modal = new Modal(driver);
            modal.SubmitForm();

            driver.Navigate().Refresh();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            var emailFound = wait.Until((d) => d.PageSource.Contains(email));
            Assert.True(emailFound);

            driver.Quit();
        }
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.
Thank you,

Comment: Do you have to use selenium? Another idea might be to use a unit testing framework like NUnit, and mock out the data layer with a framework like Moq. That would allow you to test your application logic without hitting the database.

Comment: Yes I have to use selenium.  We are testing the UI.

Comment: Do you have access to any classes or code to delete data from the database? If so, you could delete the data for this test after the test is complete. Other than that, you basically stuck with what you have.

Comment: @GregBurghardt My test project is in a separate solution from the project I am testing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are not running this on PROD, but as others have suggested and if you have read/write access to you test database write you logic to delete user from table in your clean up code.

- Moq library is useful for unit testing but wouldn't be good with Selenium, as it seems that you are trying to validate a Post-back to ensure that the user you had created does appear on the page.